# Can't compile a c# script when i use UnityEngine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vim, vim-plugin

This is my first post here, so, I'm sorry if any information is missing. I have a code that I believe is written correctly.

I`m trying to use Vim as my c# editor and using to make scripts in Unity. Every time I try to compile this code I got this error message. I have the last version of omnisharp and youcompleteme installed.

Also i have dotnet package and mono installed correctly i think. Anybody had a similar problem?

````
  2 using System.Collections.Generic;                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  3 using UnityEngine;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  4 using UnityEngine.UI;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  6 public class ControlaJogador : MonoBehaviour                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  7     ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  8 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  9     // Start is called before the first frame update                                                                                                                                                                                               
 10     void Start()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 11     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 12     ┆                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 13     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 15     // Update is called once per frame                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 16     void Update()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 17     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 18     ┆  float eixoX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 19     ┆  float eixoZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 21     ┆  Vector3 direcao = new Vector3(eixoX, 0 , eixoZ);                                                                                                                                                                                            
 22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 23     ┆  transform.Translate(Vector3.direcao);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 24     ┆                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 25     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 26                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 27 }```

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             


```$ csc ControlaJogador.cs                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ControlaJogador.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
ControlaJogador.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
ControlaJogador.cs(6,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MonoBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Mono JIT compiler version 6.10.0.104 (tarball Fri Jun 26 19:38:24 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          yes(610)
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)

dotnet --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
3.1.301
````

Comment: Well, first of all welcome to stackoverflow! Why do you want to use `vim` and compile everything manually, if there is a free Visual Studio Code? Also, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe#differences-between-c-compiler-and-c-compiler-output) (i guess you need to specify `-target:library` and `-reference:<IDK-Your-Unity-Library-Name>.dll`).

Comment: oh *vim*, i thought that died out in the 1995's

Comment: By the way UnityScript is a Javascript derivative created specifically for Unity, and it was deprecated in favour of C#. Note that C# and UnityScript are two completely different programming languages. I've removed your `[unityscript]` tag because of this.